# SSRS rdl Reporting service LocalReport error in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I am new to SSRS Report, I'm using this code to connect with ssrs rdl file,

```
rvSample.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
rvSample.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"D:\Karthik\Projects\SSRS\WithoutParameter\WithoutParameter\Report.rdl";
rvSample.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

While I am running it it shows an error,

> An error occurred during local report processing. The report definition for report 'Network Security Compliance-Auto-Phase2' has
>   not been specified Access to the path
>   'D:\Karthik\Projects\SSRS\WithoutParameter\WithoutParameter\Report.rdl'
>   is denied

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The service account running your web application needs access to the path specified in the error.  Fix it by moving the report file to the same directory structure as your web application, or by getting your web application's service account access to the file location.